# NFS client requests file one at a time when listing directory

Tags: nfs

My company has a distributed infrastructure where we host an NFS share over the VPN. The file transfer speed isn't bad, but it takes forever to list files in some directories.

I did some packet capture analysis and found out that when the `ls` command is executed for a mounted directory, a file handle request is sent to the server for each file in the directory, and each request is sent only when a response is received for the previous request. This means that given a NFS client connecting with 100ms latency and a directory with 100 files, running `ls` would take a full 10 seconds!

There must be something configured incorrectly, right? Or is this a limitation of NFSv3? Would NFSv4 help in my situation?

Comment: nfs4 can't help here. on high latency connections, try more aggressive caching options: check acregmax and acdirmax  mount options.

Comment: So the sending of one request at a time is nfs's behaviour by design? Would it be less painful to simply convert it to a Samba share?

Comment: I am afraid, the metadata operations with any network file system is a pain over high latency connections. But I am not a samba expert.

Comment: We have CIFS shares in our network that don't suffer from the same problem, since a single request is made and a stream of responses is returned. None of the ping pong stuff that nfs seems to do.